# Got VPS, need help understanding how to set up domain

Tags: domain, vps, nameserver

I am renting a VPS and with 1 dedicated IP and I don't know how to add a domain. I have my domain registered with namecheap. I know how to create nameservers on namecheap but I don't know what the IP should be, should it be my main IP. So how can I get my domain linked to my VPS.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, I have openPanel installed as a control panel. It's ok, but I feel it's lacking in a lot of departments. Are there any other free control panels that are good for a newbie?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to configure DNS then set an A-Record to your IP. Let's say for example

```
www.example.com  A  192.168.0.1
```

For this you have to know some things:

- your IP bought with the VPS
- the domain bought at namecheap

You then link them in your DNS configuration.